# Кластеризация графа. Python

Tags: python, графы, кластеризация

Есть БД, которая имеет такую структуру:

"vertex1" "vertex2" weight

---

Например:

"Слово1" "Слово2" 0.3

"Слово3" "Слово1" 0.8

"Слово4" "Слово2" 0.001

Нужно из такой базы составить граф и потом его кластеризировать.
К сожалению, graph_tool я так и не понял как применть (документация скудная + непонятно как "прикрутить" к кластеризации "вес ребра").

А установка SciPy на мою windows 10 оказалась сущим адом, которую я так и не смог преодолеть.

Может есть еще инструменты для решения оной задачи, иль по-другому нужно подходить к её решению?

Comment: Рекомендую задать отдельный вопрос "как установить scipy" на Windows 10 (по сути, scipy это набор (distribution),  который маскируется под Питон-модуль, именно чтобы облегчить установку научных пакетов до существования conda, поддержки бинарных wheel в pip итд). Типичный процесс установки не требует никакой компиляции. Прежде чем дальше двигаться, освойтесь с установкой Питон-модулей (не стоит свою библиотеку работы с графами создавать, только потому что не получилось какой-то пакет поставить).

Comment: та я поэтому и спрашивал, чтобы велосипеды не писать (уж долго это было бы, а сроки не резиновые). Но Я уже разобрался с scipy. Походу 64-битніе версии модулей питона на винду ставить нельзя(ибо не ставятся). Но 32-х битаня версия стала как родная. Но все равно - спасибо за ответ:)

Comment: это не ответ (он ничего о кластеризации не говорит), это комментарий (в любом случае форма ответа внизу, а не здесь). Ещё раз: если не знаете как поставить scipy (64-битный или нет, удовлетворяющий ещё какому-нибудь неназванному свойству или нет), то задайте отдельный подробный (со всеми требованиями) вопрос (расскажите какие конкретно шаги выполняли, что ожидали получить, что вместо этого получается, подробно, шаг за шагом). Я только что зашёл на http://scipy.org и нажал install кнопку, которая ведёт на страницу с инструкциями, которые выглядят разумно (убедитесь, что они не работают для вас)